# Checking for missing parameter in function

Tags: javascript

Is this the correct way to check for a missing parameter in a function? Would this work in all browsers? How about IE?

```
function getName(name){
    name = name != null ? name : "default";
    return name;
}
```

Comment: How does one define "correct" in this instance? To give you the best answer, we'd need to know the contexts in which the parameter should be overwritten.

Comment: Recently, I asked whether it was possible to list the names of each missing parameter in a JavaScript function, and I found plenty of interesting solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17387222/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you can do:

```
name = name || 'default';
```

That says if `name` is undefined or falsy (`null`, `0`, `""`, `false`, `{}`, `[]`), set it to `"default"`.

js(h|l)int will complain about it, but it works at least as far as back as IE7.  It's not invalid code at all or relying on some undocumented behavior either.

Comment: This of course would make falsy arguments seem to be "missing." Depending on what you're doing, this could mean a lot of false positives.

Comment: Yes it would.  But if name is supposed to be something or "default" this guarantees it.  If `name` can be `false`, `""` or something else that's empty, then no, you can't use this method, but why set a default if you're not going to use it capture empty or incorrect cases.

Comment: There are cases where you'd want to have a default value if the variable is undefined while allowing 0 or empty strings to be valid values. What you're doing will butcher all falsy values indiscriminately.

Comment: Falsy is not the same as missing.

Comment: I recommend learning [the pros and cons to each method and picking the right tool for the job](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12715304/497418).

Comment: @NullUserException there are cases.  I never said that this solved for all of those cases and I even enumerated what were the cases in which you'd get `default` and not the value passed in. This is a quick shortcut that resolves the issue. If the OP needs to pass in undefined, empty strings, null, etc, they will have to modify the solution. Personally I use `_.isUndefined` for testing this stuff since `undefined` returns `true` in that scenario.

Comment: This wasn't meant to be a dig at your answer; just pointing out possible flaws with this approach.

Comment: The original question asked to check if an argument was missing, not to supply a default if it was missing.

Answer (score 63):

The way to check for parameters depends on what type of information you're passing to the function, and how you want your function to handle edge cases.

In most cases, you can use:

```
...
bar = bar || ...default value here...
...
```

However, it might be an issue when you want to pass in falsey values (`false`, `0`, `NaN`, `''`, `undefined`, `null`):

```js
function foo(bar) {
  bar = bar || 5
  console.log(bar)
}

foo()          // 5
foo(undefined) // 5
foo(null)      // 5
foo(1)         // 1
foo(0)         // 5, probably not what you wanted
```

Instead, you can check against `undefined`:

```
...
if (bar == undefined) {
    bar = 5
}
...
```

...however using the loose check allows both `null` and `undefined` to be overwritten (`null == undefined`):

```js
function foo(bar) {
  if (bar == undefined) {
      bar = 5
  }
  console.log(bar)
}

foo()          // 5
foo(undefined) // 5
foo(null)      // 5
foo(1)         // 1
```

So instead, a strict equality comparison (`===`) is generally preferred (`null !== undefined`):

```js
function foo(bar) {
  if (bar === undefined) { 
      bar = 5
  }
  console.log(bar)
}

foo()          // 5
foo(undefined) // 5
foo(null)      // null
foo(1)         // 1
```

ES2015 introduced [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters), which are essentially equivalent to strict checking against `undefined`:

```js
function foo(bar = 5) {
  console.log(bar)
}

foo()          // 5
foo(undefined) // 5
foo(null)      // null
foo(1)         // 1
```

This could lead to trouble if you need to know whether `undefined` was passed as a parameter.

If you want to be absolutely certain that you're not passing up an argument that was provided, you can check the number of arguments passed to the function:

```
...
if (arguments.length < 1) {
  bar = 5
}
...
```

Which means that you can successfully pass `undefined` as an argument while also choosing to use a different default:

```js
function foo(bar) {
  if (arguments.length < 1) {
    bar = 5
  }
  console.log(bar)
}

foo()          // 5
foo(undefined) // undefined
foo(null)      // null
foo(1)         // 1
```

---

If you have multiple parameters, you may want to use multiple defaults. I've recently found a use case for fallthrough on a switch statement, although [the utility is questionable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12537937/implicit-fall-through-code-smell-or-elegant-design):

```js
function foo(bar, baz, fizz, buzz) {
  switch (arguments.length) {
    case 0:
      bar = 1;
      //continue; might as well point out that implicit fall-through is desired
    case 1:
      baz = 2;
      //continue;
    case 2:
      fizz = 3;
      //continue;
    case 3:
      buzz = 4;
      //continue;
  }
  console.log(bar, baz, fizz, buzz)
}

foo()               // 1 2 3 4
foo(10)             // 10 2 3 4
foo(10, 20)         // 10 20 3 4
foo(10, 20, 30)     // 10 20 30 4
foo(10, 20, 30, 40) // 10 20 30 40
```

Comment: Quite comprehensive and a better answer for the range of problems.

Comment: Thanks for such a thorough answer.

Comment: Strangely, even though ES2015 introduced default values for parameters, it still doesn't thow a syntax error if a function call is missing an argument that is specified as a parameter without a default value. This differs from most other programming languages, including C and PHP.

Answer (score 10):

The correct way to check is

```
if (typeof name === "undefined") {
    // ...
}
```

Of course callers can still "fool" you by calling `getName(undefined)`, when a parameter has been provided but the check will flag it as not-provided nonetheless. But that's really a pathological scenario.

Comment: if you do the `name = name || "default"` method though, passing in `undefined` still works as you'd expect.

Comment: @tkone Jon is talking about a possible false positive.

Comment: @NullUserException not when i left my comment.  answer has been edited since then.

Comment: @tkone: Er, no. Hover the times to see that the answer was posted 2 full minutes before the comment.

Comment: The triple equal sign === is unnecessary, since typeof always has type String. So the minimal test for the presence of a necessary argument is "if (typeof name=="undefined")...".

Answer (score 0):

Yes this would work in all browsers though if you want to see if it is defined you might use:

```
function getName(name){
   name = typeof(name) !== "undefined" ? name : "default";
   return name;
}
```

Comment: Requires more characters than the standard '||' answer. Not needed anyway in modern browsers, which support default values in function parameters.