# How can I get the names of missing arguments in a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, function

```
function fnDrawPrism(length, width, height){
        //If any of these parameters are undefined, throw an error that lists the missing parameters.
        return length*width*height;
}
```

In JavaScript, I'm trying to obtain the names of all parameters in a function that are `undefined`. If any of the parameters in this function are undefined, then I want the function to throw an error that lists the names of the missing parameters.

I've found a solution to this problem, but it requires a separate conditional statement for every parameter, and I want to know if there's a more concise way to obtain a list of undefined parameters:

```
var toReturn = "";
if((typeof length == "undefined") || (length == "undefined")){
    toReturn += "length is not defined!";
}
if((typeof width == "undefined") || (width == "undefined")){
    toReturn += "width is not defined!";
}
if((typeof height == "undefined") || (height == "undefined")){
    toReturn += "height is not defined!";
}
if(toReturn != ""){
    throw new Error(toReturn); //if any parameters are missing, then list the names of all missing parameters
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `|| (length == "undefined")` part, unless you're concerned somebody might call your function and actually deliberately pass that string with `fnDrawPrism("undefined")`.

Comment: Do you think [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) could solve your problem

Comment: @aaronman Yes, but then I'd need a way to get the name of each parameter from the arguments array.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to test that each argument is actually the type you expect (in this case a number) rather than testing if it is undefined? If I say `fnDrawPrism("a","b","c")` no arguments are missing, but you'll still have a problem...

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes, but then I'd still need to find a way to get the name of each parameter in the `arguments` array.

Comment: Why are the names so important? Isn't a generic "missing argument" exception enough? How about a compromise with "Argument 2 is missing" or something like that? Also, what do you actually mean by "missing"? There's no way the first argument can be missing if the second and third are provided (but the first could be `undefined` in that case)...

Comment: @nnnnnn I want to call the function using named arguments, as described here, so obtaining a list of missing parameter names is actually useful in this case: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/namedfunction.shtml

Comment: Yes, named arguments is the usual way to define most JS functions. I just don't think actually using the names in an exception for missing arguments is really necessary. But if that's your requirement, well, that's what this question is about, obviously.

Comment: @nnnnnn That was the best approach that I could think of, but there might be other approaches to this problem as well. Is there any better way to ensure that all of the named arguments in a function are defined?

Comment: @AndersonGreen The simplest way is to just compare the number of arguments passed to the function `arguments.length` to the number of named arguments (see my answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a stand-alone validation function that you can use from any function to check the passed arguments for presence and type-correctness using Hungarian notation:

```
function fnDrawPrism(length, numWidth, intHeight){
    //If any of these parameters are undefined, throw an error that lists the missing parameters.
    // you can cut-and-past the declaration line to fill out 90% of the validation call:
    validate(fnDrawPrism, length, numWidth, intHeight); 

    return length * numWidth * intHeight;
}

// this is cut-and-pasted into a file somewhere, edit to add more types or stricter checking
function validate(args){
    var fn = args, actuals = [].slice.call(arguments, 1),
        hung = {int: "Number", num: "Number", str: "String", arr: "Array",
        obj: "Object", inp: "HTMLInputElement", dt: "Date", bln: "Boolean",
        rx: "RegExp", frm: "HTMLFormElement", doc: "HTMLDocument"},
        names = String(fn).split(/\s*\)\s*/)[0].split(/\s*\(\s*/)[1].split(/\s*\,\s*/),
        mx = names.length, i = 0;
    if(!fn.name)
        fn.name = String(fn).split(/\s*(/)[0].split(/\s+/)[1] || 'anon';
    for(i; i < mx; i++){
        if(actuals[i] === undefined)
            throw new TypeError("missing arg #" + i + " in " + fn.name + " - " + names[i]);
        var hint = hung[names[i].split(/[A-Z]/)[0]],
            got = toString.call(actuals[i]).split(/\W/)[2];
        if(hint && got !== hint)
            throw new TypeError("Wrong type in argument #" + i + " of " + fn.name + " - " + names[i] + ". Got: " + got + ", Expected: " + hint);
}

//try it out:
fnDrawPrism(1);       //! missing arg #1 in fnDrawPrism - numWidth
fnDrawPrism(1,4);     //! missing arg #2 in fnDrawPrism - intHeight
fnDrawPrism(1,2,3);   // ok
fnDrawPrism(1,"2",3); //! Wrong type in argument #1 of fnDrawPrism - numWidth. Got: string, Expected: number
```

the reason you can;t just pass "arguments" to the validator is that strict mode imposes too many restrictions on the arguments object to reliably use it. Ecma6 will have a way of passing all args in one go, but then that will only work on future browsers, while the long-hand way works in browsers then, now, and forever...

EDIT: update validation routine based on comments to be a little stronger, adding documents, inputs, forms, arrays, regexp, dates, and objects to the Hungarian notation validation routine, which also now works across window objects.

Comment: It looks like someone just downvoted this question for no apparent reason. I'm really puzzled by all of the random downvoting that I've seen on this question (and its answers).

Comment: FYI: to test if an object is an array, the best technique comes from http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.2 : `{}.toString.call([]).replace(/^\[object\s+(.*)\]$/, '$1') === 'Array'`

Comment: this is meant to be a simple start to something custom, and within the "i don't mind dropping this in" weight-class. It can certainly be made to be stricter and recognize more object types like dates, regexp, element, whatev...

Comment: @Nirk: or, simpler, v=/./ ; toString.call(v).split(/\W/)[2]

Comment: I'll upvote for the effort but I think it's an overkill and that an approach like shift66 used is preferable.

Comment: Holy **** JavaScript is so messed up.  Dumbest decision to allow calling functions with wrong argument lists _by default..._  Even linters don't catch it.  And look what we have to do to catch these errors.  ****.

Comment: @SO_fix_the_vote_sorting_bug I think "decision" is generous, considering JS was created in a week and cloned by M$ months later, locking the design for interop sake. TBF, a dynamic-typed C-style interpreted design borrowing function-ality from LISP was state of the art at the time and many of the knobs had yet to be dialed in or tuned to multi-file codebases. OTOH, being able to pass a date as a string, number, or object and have it just "work" was/is impressive and it's current popularity speaks to the robustness of that original design, as we _can_ bolt superstructure on as-needed.

Answer (score 3):

you can hold them in an object and iterate through it's keys:

```
function fnDrawPrism(length, width, height){
    var params = {
        length: length,
        height: height,
        width: width
    }

    for(var field in Object.keys(params))
    {
        if(params[field] === undefined)
        {/* do what you want */}
    }
    ...
}
```

**EDIT for people who don't want to think a little bit more**

this should be done **in the function**.

Comment: This means completely changing the API; and for worse, imo.

Comment: @naomik Which API is being changed here?

Comment: @naomik thinks that I suggest you to make an object and pass it to the function (i.e change function declaration to function(params){...})

Comment: Feisty. I like it. I just wasn't making assumptions about your code. Be more explicit next time and there will be less room for assumptions to be made.

Answer (score 2):

There is no simple way in javascript to obtain the name of the 1st or 2nd or nth argument to a function.  It may be possible to examine the string version of the function and parse them out, but I rather doubt you want to do that.

You can build your own list of the names in an array or object and then use the `arguments` object to iterate over the arguments checking each one for validity and then use your own array of names to obtain the name of the nth one if it has an error.

For example, you could check each argument like this:

```
function fnDrawPrism(length, width, height){
    //If any of these parameters are undefined, throw an error that lists the missing parameters.
    var argNames = ["length", "width", "height"];
    if (arguments.length < argNames.length) {
        // throw first arg that is missing
        throw new Error(argNames[arguments.length] + " is undefined");
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        if (arguments[i] === undefined) {
            throw new Error(argNames[i] + " is undefined");
        }
    }
    // now that all args are defined do the business of the function
    return length*width*height;
}
```

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/9PH6P/

---

If you wanted to restructure your code and pass a single object with keys/values as the arguments, then it is much easier to iterate over them and obtain the arg names from the passed object keys.  But, I assumed you were asking a question about a normal function call with multiple arguments so that's the answer I provided above.

Comment: I think there's a syntax error here: I got `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` in the browser console when I tried running this function.

Comment: @jcsanyi - all  of your issues fixed.

Comment: @jcsanyi - yep, you're right - sorry.  Changed that too.  That's what I get for trying to do other things while also answering here.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track - Here's how I would extract that out to a helper function, and make the error thrown more informative by listing *all* the missing arguments:

```
function validateParams(names, vals) {
    var missing = [];
    for (var i=0; i<names.length; i++) {
        if (vals[i] === undefined) missing.push(names[i]);
    }
    if (missing.length > 0) throw "Missing arguments: " + missing.join(', ');
}

function fnDrawPrism(length, width, height){
    validateParams(['length', 'width', 'height'], [length, width, height]);
    return length * width * height;
}
```

Comment: +1 - not sure why someone else downvoted this.  Looks like an interesting solution to me.

Comment: @jfriend00 One of the hazards of answering this particular question seems to be that you get an automatic downvote.

Comment: Yeah, it does appear that every answer to this question has at least one downvote.

Comment: @jcsanyi I haven't downvoted any of these answers myself, and I'm still not sure why this has happened.

Answer (score 0):

You can pull the names by using [Function.prototype.toString](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.2):

```
function get_args(fn) {
    return fn.toString().match(/\((.*)\)/)[1].split(", ")
}
```

For your function:

```
function fnDrawPrism(length, width, height){
    return length*width*height;
}
get_args(fnDrawPrism) // [ 'length', 'width', 'height' ]
```

Comment: I suspect that this question's answers have been attacked by a serial downvoter. Almost every answer to this question was downvoted immediately after the answer was posted.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion a more generic "Argument 2 is missing" type exception is adequate - the developer seeing such an exception would then go and check what argument 2 actually is. Also, it might be better to talk about "undefined" rather than "missing", since somebody might say `fnDrawPrism(undefined, 1, 2);` in which case the first argument isn't actually "missing".

Anyway, if you're determined to display the names here's what I came up with, using `.toString()` and a regex on the function to get the argument names:

```
function fnDrawPrism(length, width, height){
    var msg = [],
        argNames = fnDrawPrism.toString().match(/\(([^)]*)\)/)[1].split(/\s*,\s*/);
    for (var i = 0; i < fnDrawPrism.length; i++)  // for each declared argument
      if (typeof arguments[i] === "undefined")
          msg.push(argNames[i]);
    if (msg.length > 0)
        throw new Error("fnDrawPrism missing argument(s): " + msg.join(", "));

    // ACTUAL function body goes here
}
```

Assuming you want to do similar validation in all of your functions you can pull that out into a separate function:

```
function testFuncArgs(fn, args) {
    var msg = [], argNames = fn.toString().match(/\(([^)]*)\)/)[1].split(/\s*,\s*/);
    for (var i = 0; i < fn.length; i++)   // for each declared argument
      if (typeof args[i] === "undefined")
          msg.push(argNames[i]);
    if (msg.length > 0)
        throw new Error("Function "+fn.name+" missing argument(s): "+ msg.join(", "));
}

function fnDrawPrism(length, width, height){
    testFuncArgs(fnDrawPrism, arguments);

    // ACTUAL function body goes here
}

function someOtherFunction(a, b, c, d){
    testFuncArgs(someOtherFunction, arguments);

    // Actual function body here
}
```

Note that you may like to add an additional check for cases when somebody calls your function with too many arguments, i.e., `if (arguments.length > fnDrawPrism.length)`.

Comment: It appears that almost every new answer to this question is being downvoted. What's going on here? :/

Comment: I think it was unfair to downvote the question, too. As I stated earlier in comments above I think your goal is overkill, but still figuring out how to do it is interesting so I actually _upvoted_ the question. My answer was downvoted so quickly I don't think the person involved could've even read it thoroughly. Anyway, I've been around StackOverflow long enough to have seen that happen quite a few times so I don't let it bother me.

Comment: I hate when people downvote things without explaining themselves. I'm upvoting this because it takes the interesting approach of *not* storing the arguments in an extra array or object, and is well explained. Shame on you, downvoter!

Comment: Thanks @Dan. I tried to come up with an approach that could easily be applied to multiple functions; for a single function it's not worth the trouble...