# Confused on a piece of code, specifically null : Eloquent Javascript practice

Tags: javascript

As you can see this code is fairly straightforward, i actually understand most of it, but the only part that confuses me is the beginning if statement and more specifically the use of null. from what i have read, null becomes the value or a stand in, unlike undefined where it is simply that, undefined. so why use null in this case?

```
function range(start, end, step) {
  if (step == null) step = 1;
  var array = [];

  if (step > 0) {
    for (var i = start; i <= end; i += step)
      array.push(i);
  } else {
    for (var i = start; i >= end; i += step)
      array.push(i);
  }
  return array;
}

function sum(array) {
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    total += array[i];
  return total;
}

console.log(range(1, 10))
// → [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
console.log(range(5, 2, -1));
// → [5, 4, 3, 2]
console.log(sum(range(1, 10)));
// → 55
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the function is called without the `step` parameter it will set it to `1` by default.

so here:

```
console.log(range(1, 10)
/ → [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

there is no "step" included.. but the output shows step has been set to 1.  in the following examples, step IS included so that value is used instead.

Comment: that was the answer i was looking for, thank you. i realized that after spending a fair amount of time staring blankly.

Answer (score 1):

`step` would be undefined if left out of the call to range, the reason why this works is because of the weak comparison `null == undefined` is true, but if we use stricter evaluation i.e. `null === undefined` we get false.

Comment: A good explanation can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12715157/checking-for-missing-parameter-in-function

Answer (score 0):

In javascript function if a certain parameter is not supplied the it is undefined. here in code it should be

```
if (step === undefined) step = 1;
```

It is always better practice to use strict comparison. Because `null==undefined` also `undefined== null`, the code works. You should modify the code as mentioned.

Comment: Thanks @ Ouroborus

Comment: I disagree that it's always best practice to use strict comparison. Sometimes you want the parameter to accept either null or undefined, either because you may be passing in a value from somewhere else that can be null, or because using the null check is substantially shorter. (one char saved with the standard == instead of ===, and 5 chars saved with null instead of undefined) Yes, the positives are minor, but so are the negatives, and I'd say more so. Apart from the initial learning of the differences, I've never had any issues just using the "== null" check; that said, either way is fine.